# Is it possible to know if a PowerShell script is launched from GUI or console?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to know if a PowerShell script is launched from GUI e.g. double-click in the explorer or manually in a powershell console?

I would like to use an interactive console mode if it's launched in GUI / explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query `$host` automatic variable

```
$host.name
```

return the name of the actual host.

Comment: I think I made a mistake, because PowerShell Script can not be started by double click from explorer :( (for comparison: old *.bat and *.cmd files can be launched by double-click)